# Avconv Error when trying to save an updating snapshot of an IP-camera stream

Tags: ubuntu, avconv

I'm trying to save an updating image of my camera stream on my Desktop.

```
avconv -i rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.199/h264 -f image2 -r 1
/home/nuc/Images/img.jpg
```

Protocol

```
avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 10 2014 18:16:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[h264 @ 0x1eb8180] RTP: missed 5 packets
[h264 @ 0x1eb8180] concealing 2447 DC, 2447 AC, 2447 MV errors
[rtsp @ 0x1eb4020] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.199/h264':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000044, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 25 fps, 45k tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Output #0, image2, to '/home/nuc/Bilder/img.jpg':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 1 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[h264 @ 0x1fe5740] concealing 2447 DC, 2447 AC, 2447 MV errors
```

Error:

```
Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '/home/nuc/Bilder/img.jpg'
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
nuc@nuc:~$
```

Comment: Does [this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271357/ffmpeg-on-fb0-from-nexus-galaxy-error-could-not-get-frame-filename-number-2)?

Comment: @E Carter Young Unfortunately not. I wan't to update the same file. The answer in the link creates a sequence of files.

Comment: I believe you need a sequence of files as img.jpg contains multiple frames

Comment: @E Carter Young img.jpg is just the location where it is saving. I want to update it 5 times a second (or more).